# Opening Kontakt with a preloaded library

Tags: kontakt

Is it possible to configure Kontakt so that when opening, a certain library would already be loaded?

Comment: Is this possibly a support question for NI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just double-click on the nki file will launch Kontakt (standalone) and load the instrument file.

If you want to ease the insertion of a track with a preloaded Kontakt, some software like Reaper have templates : you create the track with Kontakt and the nki file, save it as a template. Then adding a similar track will just need to select this template. I have as many templates as my favourite instruments. (Reaper has project templates and track templates).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Do you know, is there a similar function with templates in FL?

Comment: There are project templates in FL Studio. See https://youtu.be/kPg3jUvpGwk they are just project saved in FL Studio Data folder\FL Studio\Projects\Templates   I don’t think there are track templates.